# How can i get the text entered in search in action bar to a string?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have an activity that shows search in title bar perfectly, but right now i want to get the text entered in search in action bar to a string. Please help !

Her is my menu/xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="Search"
      android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
      android:showAsAction="always"
       android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
      />


</menu>
```

Her is the code in onCreate

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
     ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you used `searchView`? You can use following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search)
            .getActionView();
    if (null != searchView) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    }

    SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            // This is your adapter that will be filtered
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            // **Here you can get the value "query" which is entered in the search box.**

        }
    };
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a **Toolbar** you can do this:

```
MenuItem menuItem = getToolbar().getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_search);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            Log.i("well", " this worked");
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Log.i("well", " this worked");
            return false;
        }
    });
```